Change layout (side margins) in the Springer Nature LaTeX Template
I use the Springer Nature LaTeX Template to write my article but the side margins are to big:

Can you help me to change the sizes, there are a class (cls) file with the settings but I do not know what I have to change to change the sizes of the margin, top and the bottom?

Don't change the margins if you want to submit your article to the journal of which the template you use.

Welcome to TeX.SE! Without seeing any code it is hard to help you, sorry.

That is correct, but I do not know which code are interesting, there is the tex-file in which the documentclass is sn-mathphys-num and then the cls file with the format and lyout but in this file there is many commands/settings and i do not know, on witch section i have to change anything...

@Skillmon For this task i have to change it, because that is not a article for springer. I use this because I like this template for latex.

journal classes like springer's are designed not to be easily customisable, the whole point is to remove author choice and force the journal style (and page size) why use the springer class at all if you do not want to print on the paper size of their journals?

You can probably load the geometry package and reset the page size using its options, but I can not advise that.

If you are printing your document and you want to crop the margins, there is a nice tool called  pdfcrop that comes with latex distribution. See this
